# Cannot find indicator-synapse config file

Tags: release-freya, applications

I am using freya(64bit) and have installed indicator-synapse from the ppa found here:
[install indicator-synapse](http://www.webupd8.org/2013/06/synapse-indicator-new-search.html)

Everything is working fine, but i just can't find the "config.json" file which is supposed to be at `~/.config/synapse/config.json`  according to [indicator-synapse configuration](http://synapse.zeitgeist-project.com/wiki/index.php?title=Plugins/Configuration)

[here: jules' answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/174838/can-i-change-synapse-shortcut-to-super-windows-key-alone) says the default path for the config file has been changed to `~/.config/hotkeys/synapse/synapse.hotkeys`. But I cannot find hotkeys dir neither in ~/.config/ nor /home/username/.config/

So, can anyone please guide me to the path to this file.

Comment: Not a direct answer to you question, but you might be better of knowing about "Find" if you have not tried it yet. http://www.tecmint.com/35-practical-examples-of-linux-find-command/

Comment: I think both of those links are referring to synapse rather than indicator-synapse

Answer (score 1):

I do searches differently, perhaps run "sudo updatedb" then follow with "sudo locate config.json"
This should locate the file if it was generated.

Answer (score -1):

You can try finding it by using these commands:

```
whereis indicator-synapse
```

or

```
find indicator-synapse
```

Comment: Have already tried these, but to no avail.